# zf2 decodeGzip, why is it protected?

Tags: zend-framework2, gzip

I'm getting back what appears to be gzipped data in a call to a zf2 api. The content-type is gzip, and the content body looks encoded. So I tried this:

```
    $decoded = $response->decodeGzip($response->getContent());
```

and I got back this error:

```
Call to protected method Zend\Http\Response::decodeGzip()
```

Why is it protected? It seems like decoding gzipped data would be a handy thing to be able to do.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `$response->getBody()`. The `getBody()` method checks the `Content-Encoding` header and if this is gzip, it will extract the body from the Gzipped content.

You can check this method in the online repository: [Zend\Http\Response](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/7688fab93de0b94c3469c798cbb2d36d301bfce3/library/Zend/Http/Response.php#L307-L336)